# How to get Uploaded filename in java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try{
        sentfilename = printNames(request);
        MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request, ImageDirecoty, 1024*1024*5);
    } catch(IOException e){
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT, "File limit has exceeded or it wasn't an actual image");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
}

public String printNames(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException{
        for(Part part : request.getParts()){
            Collection<String> headers = part.getHeaders("content-disposition");
            if (headers == null)
                continue;
            for(String header : headers){
                String filename = header.substring(header.indexOf("filename=") + 10 , header.length());
                String result = filename.replace("\"", "");
                return result;
            } 
        }
        return null;
}
```

Basically I am uploading a simple file from client, Now I need to get the filename out of the request data which successfully can be taken through `printNames` function and write the request data to my `filepath`, Now the problem is that as you can see in my `doPost() try` if I put `printNames` function first I can get the filename but it doesn't write the data and if I put `MultipartRequest` first I can get the fileupload but I don't get the filename.

Hope that don't make any confusion and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can get it from the part object itself

`String fileName = part.getSubmittedFileName();`

example:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Deque<FileInfo> files = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Part part : req.getParts()) {
        long fileSize = part.getSize();
        String fileName = part.getSubmittedFileName();
        if (fileSize == 0 && (fileName == null || fileName.isEmpty())) {
            continue; // Ignore part, if not a file.
        }
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(UUID.randomUUID(), fileSize, fileName, part.getContentType());

        files.add(info);
        Files.copy(part.getInputStream(), new File(uploads, info.getId().toString()).toPath());
    }

    req.getSession().setAttribute("uploadedFiles", files);
    resp.sendRedirect(applicationUrl + "/upload");
}
```

source: http://ursaj.com/upload-files-in-java-with-servlet-api

Hope it helps!

Comment: and where do you call the `MultipartRequest()`

Comment: with servlet-api 3.1 you can simply annotate the servlet class `@WebServlet ...
@MultipartConfig(
    fileSizeThreshold = 16768,
    maxRequestSize = 10L * 1024 * 1024,
    maxFileSize = 10L * 1024 * 1024
)`

Comment: Somehow that isn't working with me, I kind of have to use `MultipartRequest()` itself, do you have any idea of to do it with `MultipartRequest()`

Comment: I think I need further information now. It's hard to understand what you want to achieve. It would be great if you can provide some more details on: used technologies, versions, configuration files etc.

Comment: I just want to get the filename out of the `multipartRequest` sent from client before saving the uploaded file.